# select items in a checkbox list based on their text

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a check box list in my asp.net page ...i need to select the check box based on their text...am getting these string values form the database and storing it in a array.....the below code works fine for a single text ..What should i do in case of array..how should i pass the array values in the if loop

```
 for (int i = 0; i < chkbx.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (chkbx.Text == "Dress" )

            {

                chkbx.Items[i].Selected = true;

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code should work for you -

```
string[] array = { "Dress", "Pen", "Table"};

    for (int i = 0; i < chkbx.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (array.Contains(chkbx.Items[i].Text))
        {
            chkbx.Items[i].Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use the **Contains** method of the array that contains your text values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < chkbx.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (myArray.Contains(chkbx.Items[i].Text))
    {
        chkbx.Items[i].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

where `myArray` is the array of values you're populating from the database.

Comment: it does not work, myArray.Contains(chkbx.Text) never returns true

Comment: Can you show the code that populates the array you are checking against in your question?

Comment: adding this (chkbx.Items[i].Text ) instead of chkbx.Text worked thanks for your help

Comment: Don't you want `myArray.Contains(chkbx.Items[i].Text)`?

Comment: Yup you are both right, I messed that small detail up.  Fixed in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a nice way of doing it

```
foreach (string item in myarr)
            {
                checkboxlist1.Items[checkboxlist1.Items.IndexOf(checkboxlist1.Items.FindByText(item))].Selected = true;
            }
```